# Scrollable panel keep changing position of controls in compile. VB.NET - C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, panel, scrollable

I have a scrollable panel in which I have a lot of controls. Everything is fine, the design looks great, but the problem is when I press compile every control in panel change their main position which result a big blank space in the panel and looks totally ugly.

And not only that, after I close the compiled application, the controls inside panel from Visual Studio designer are changed in the same way as the compiled app so I have to change their position manually again.

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: I think we need more information.  Is this WinForms?  Are the controls normal .net ones or something custom?

Comment: Yes. WinForms. And I'm using a misc between regular controls and custom controls. I anchored all of them to the Top and it solved a little. Now it change their position a little to left... just a bit... like the width of the vertical scrollbar of main panel. I still want to fix that. I want everything to be fully centered. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. I fixed my problem by adding that scrollable panel to another panel and setting dock property to fill over that panel. Everything works fine!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what type of app you use but most of them have a locked property.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/80xxxf69(v=vs.110).aspx

maybe this is what you are looking for, if you give some more info the type of form you use etc i can have a closer look into it.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this and I still got the same problem. When I compile the executable the controls change their location in app and in the developing designer. I really don't know what to do.